# Cannot use more than 20 repositories as resources in my Azure Devops YAML file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I get this error when my pipeline tries to run: "Tokens may be scoped to a maximum of 20 repositories. Reference fewer repositories in YAML or disable Scoped Tokens."

I found this post that basically says I'm out of luck, which I really hope isn't true anymore: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/checking-out-more-than-20-repositories-in-yaml-pip/1521492

Is there a way to fix this? This is a deal breaker for our project. It says I can disable scoped tokens, what are they are how would I do that? Referencing fewer than 20 is not an alternative since we need them all.

My YAML looks something like this:

```yaml
trigger:
  - release/test

pool:
  name: <REDACTED
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED

# Overrides the value for Build.BuildNumber, which is used to name the artifact (ZIP file) that is produced
name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: REPO1
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/REPO1
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    - repository: REPO2
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED/REPO2
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    # and many more repos..


stages:
  - stage: 'BuildAndUploadArtifact'
    jobs:
      - job:
        workspace:
          clean: all
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - checkout: REPO1
          - checkout: REPO2
            # and many more repos..

 # Rest of pipeline that does stuff with the repos
```

Comment: You can't use submodules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by disabling the following option. Not sure what impact that will have though. Obviously it seems to make it less secure, but is it a big deal?:
[image]

Comment: Cancel my post as you already find the cause :) . If the option `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines` is enabled, it will requires to permit to access the repository resource, it has `20` permits limit so it will report the error. Disable the option will not require the repository permission, please refer to the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/secure-access-to-repos?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#further-configuration) for more details.